# Slang in Esperanto

Tags: esperanto, registers

Esperanto has a literature (both original and translated) including criminal stories. Criminals are often portrayed as speaking some slang, so my question is:

How does criminal slang looks like in Esperanto?

Comment: You might get more replies posting this on the Esperanto stackexchange.

Comment: Related question on [esperanto.se]: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/339/do-dialectical-variations-exist-in-esperanto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La sociolekta triopo**

Manuel Halvelik created three sociolects for Esperanto, [Arcaicam Esperantom](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcaicam_Esperantom) (1969), an archaic pre-form of Esperanto, [Popido](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popido) (1973), a constructed dialect of Esperanto, and [Gavaro](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavaro) (2006), an argot of Esperanto. *Arcaicam Esperantom* and *Popido* are used in the Esperanto literature, but I don't know a work using *Gavaro* (what is not surprising, looking at the publication date of Gavaro).

An interesting feature of Gavaro are the numerals, they are taken from Volapük and are obscure to Esperanto speakers: *1 bwal, 2 twel, 3 kwil, 4 fwol, 5 lwel, 6 mwel, 7 vwel, 8 zwul, 9 ĵwel, 10 dweg, 100 twum, 1000 mlat*.